# how to show an item of html select tag when the page is loaded

Tags: html, forms

I have a select element in my page that has different element. ie.

```
<select name="select_element">
    <option value="item_1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="item_2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="item_3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

I would to show the element `Item 2` when the page is loaded instead the first element of the list. Does exist a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you mean that the second item is selected on load? If so, use "selected" attribute - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
<select name="select_element">
    <option value="item_1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="item_2" selected>Item 2</option>
    <option value="item_3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something called "selected" that will make that option the selected option when the page is loaded. All you do is this:

```
<option value="item_1">Item 1</option>
<option value="item_2" selected>Item 2</option>
```

Hope this helped!